# using jquery to get html form input values in raw html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you use jquery (or anything else for that matter) to get the form values from the argument in the callback of a jquery.get() call provided it is html?

for instance, say the following call:

```
$.get('somePage.aspx', function (data) {  
     alert('here');
            });
```

called the callback function with the following html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="frmMontageWait.aspx?action=checkStatus&amp;guid=a224b7c3-fec8-4b55-870e-a33f15bad629" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTc5NTA2NTY5NmRkyx3R93TAvDqSvxEh6aKHeTSr0ZI=" />
</div><div> <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAwLA8/fiDgLP15SfBAKG69WwDBRTCbRBksmbw/qTkRQ4tx/K3bES" />
</div>
        <input type="hidden" name="hdnInput1" id="hdnInput1" value="100" />
        <input type="hidden" name="hdnInput2" id="hdnInput2" value="99" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How do you go about getting the values of hdnInput1 and hdnInput2 in the callback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data` variable in your code stores the server-response, you can parse it for the information you want. By default this server response will be in plain text, so you have to parse that string into a jQuery object which will create DOM elements out of the string:

```
//DOM-ize the server-response
data = $(data);

//now we can search the server-response like it is in the DOM (but it isn't)
var inputOne = data.find('#hdnInput1').val(),
    inputTwo = data.find('#hdnInput2').val();
```

This code goes in your `success` callback for your AJAX call.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PDHbV/

I'm not 100% sure that the HTML you posted is stored in the `data` variable, if it isn't then that mean the HTML is already in the DOM and you can search for it normally:

```
var inputOne = $('#hdnInput1').val(),
    inputTwo = $('#hdnInput2').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val1 = $('#hdnInput1').val();
val2 = $('#hdnInput2').val();
```

Comment: This would create global variables (which isn't necessary). To put the variables in the correct scope, use the `var` statement: `var val1 = $('#hdnInput1').val(),
val2 = $('#hdnInput2').val();`